# how to create a loop that checks for each iteration and starts back at the beginning after each iteration

Tags: c++, loops

i want to create a function that will randomly insert a space between words in a string by using a random num gen to choose either 1 or 2, then proceed to insert or to skip to the ending of the next word. i want this to only happen when the length of the string is less than the predefined limit i have put on it with the variable myLength. my main issue is that my poorly designed loop fills up the space between the first word and the second word, and does not check for the other ones.

my main issue is that my poorly designed loop fills up the space between the first word and the second word, and does not check for the other ones.

```
    void NumLoop(string& s) {

int pos = s.find_first_of(' ');

while (s.length() < myLength) {

    for (int pos; pos != string::npos; pos = s.find(' ', pos + 1)) {

        int choice = rand() % 2;

        if (choice = 1) {
            s.insert(pos + 1, " ");

                break;

        }
        if (choice = 0) {

            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << s;
system("pause");
```

}

i would like the program to randomly choose the spaces between the words and then to increase the string size until it reaches the desired s.length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this `pos`:

```
int pos = s.find_first_of(' ');
```

gets hidden by this `pos` in the scope of your `for` loop:

```
for (int pos; pos != string::npos; pos = s.find(' ', pos + 1)) {
```

so get rid of the first and combine the two as in this loop:

```
for (int pos = s.find_first_of(' '); pos != string::npos; pos = s.find(' ', pos + 1)) {
```

next, change your `break`s (which break out of the `for` loop, ending it) to `continue`s which skip to the end of the loop and, er, continue.

I think there are other problems but this will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: thanks! for some reason i always get thrown off by break and continue statements but i feel more comfortable with them now